# Query regarding to the freeradius server for windows

Tags: freeradius

Earlier we have used the freeradius version 2.2.3 for windows.
We want to test the eap-tls 1.2, We are unable to find the executable files for 3.X versions(windows support).
Could you please point me the executable file that can install in the windows PC?

Regards,
Mani

Answer (score 1):

There are no official versions of FreeRADIUS for Windows. We (the FreeRADIUS developers) do not build for Windows and do not use it.

A version of FreeRADIUS 1 was created for Windows many years by an unknown party, but the source code was never released and on that basis it is not known whether it is safe to use or not. It was not official. Version 1 and 2 are now obsolete.

FreeRADIUS 3 has never been ported to Windows. The options are

- Run it in Linux, MacOS or some other UNIX based operating system. This is the only officially supported solution. Packages are available from https://networkradius.com/, and the source is available from https://freeradius.org/.
- It may be possible to build and run in Windows Subsystem for Linux. This has not been tested by the developers and is not supported.
- It may be possible to build and run in Cygwin. Again, this has not been tested by the developers.

There are no known efforts to port FreeRADIUS to Windows natively.